# How to replace a string which contains any sequence of linefeeds and spaces with a single line feed

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to construct a PHP string replacement / regex function that takes a string with any sequence of linefeeds and spaces and replaces it with a single line feed.

Is this possible and, if so, how would it be done ?

Comment: Do you have an example of the input string and what you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Any sequence of spaces and line feeds should become one line feed? Space => line feed?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
= preg_replace('/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/', "\n", $text);
```

It will look out for a single CR or LF to detect Unix, Windows and old Mac line breaks. And after that any whitespace (space, tab, CR, LF) will be removed.

- I would however remove the first `\s*` to ignore spaces on the preceding line.
- The last `\s*` could also be `[\r\n ]*` if you want to keep \tabs.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world if you want to refine this regex.

Answer (score 1):

If the spaces/breaks can come in any sequence and from any potential OS, then this would be a shotgun approach:

```
$fixed_string = preg_replace('/[\s\n\r]+/', "\n", $bad_string);
```

It'll look for one-or-more whitespace (\s), newline (\n) and carriage return (\r) characters and replace them with a newline.

Comment: In PHP, `\s` is equivalent to `[ \t\f\r\n]`, so the `[\s\r\n]` in your regex might as well be just `\s`.  Also, I think the OP wants to match only sequences with at least one linefeed in them, and you aren't enforcing that.

Comment: Marc B - This works perfectly. Thanx much !  And Alan Moore, you are right, the results I get from these two solutions is identical.

Comment: Now I need to find a solution that will replace all white space with a '\n' but only if there exists an '\n' in the white space. I suspect that is not a regex problem (but correct me if I'm wrong.) Thanx again for all your help !

Comment: Something like `/\s+\n*\s+/' would probably do it. zero or more newline surrounded by 1 or more whitespace chars on either side.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Great source material!

Comment: That *is* a great resource, but the OP is asking a specific question and you haven't answered it.

Comment: I thought it was fairly trivial to do it, learning the basics.

Comment: True enough, but how much value does that answer add, either to this Q&A or to StackOverflow as a whole?  Especially in this case; that particular site seems to get recommended at least once every day.

Comment: I think it's a lot MORE valuable for the OP to take half an hour and go through that, and produce the answer to his question by himself, than to be given a cryptic regex string. As for SO, yes, I wasn't giving an answer to help posterity.